# Embedded HTML page security

Tags: html, security, jsp, authentication

I have an application that consists of jsp and HTML pages. It requires a login to access the site. However that doesn't seem to work on html pages. I can copy the link to the html page and access it without having to login which is the case for the jsp pages. Any ideas on how I can authenticate the default server pages?

Comment: Don't use html pages. Only use jsp pages and make sure to check the session at the top of each of them. Plain html pages obviously have no access to the server-side session.

Comment: You can add a filter and map the urls or url pattern of all the links you want to be accessed only after login. In the filter check for the authenticated session and if user is authenticated then let it pass otherwise redirect him to the login page.

Comment: So we do have the filter in place for other security measures. I guess I can play around with having these pages pass through that filter as well. Or I guess easier would be converting them to jsps. Thanks.

Comment: Could you add an answer to your question ?